# Add system versioning for a relative time period in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

I want to add system versioning for a table, "person." I want it to only store data that has changed in the past week.

Here's the best I can come up with...

```
ALTER TABLE person 
ADD PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME(ONE_WEEK_AGO, PRESENT),
ADD SYSTEM VERSIONING;
```

I am grateful for any pointers you all might have.

Comment: MySQL dies not support system versioning. Maybe you use MariaDB?

Comment: *I want to add system versioning for a table, "person." I want it to only store data that has changed in the past week.* There is no any relation between these 2 statements. use BEFORE INSERT trigger.

Comment: I removed the mysql tag, because this question is about a feature specific to mariadb. The feature of system versioning is not supported by mysql.

Answer (score 0):

I have a fix, which I think will work (pending access). It is to run this as an event...

```
SET @oneMonthAgo = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY;

DELETE HISTORY FROM person BEFORE SYSTEM_TIME @oneMonthAgo;
```